# rstudio server is not opening after stoping and restarting

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server

my rstudio server was hanging too often while loading starting r shiny app. So after googling around i tried to stop and start the rstudio server again. i also tried to kill all process running on 8787 port. But had no luck solving the issue. now r studio server keeps waiting while opening on web browser.

I have used below command to kill process running on 8787 port. after running the command there was no result.

sudo kill -TERM 20647 
(20647 is port where rserver process is listening. i got this port number after running 'sudo netstat -ntlp | grep :8787' command).

to stop and restart r studio server, i used below command
sudo rstudio-server stop
sudo rstudio-server start

expected result is working sr studio server which doesnt hang while loading shiny app.
after running status command i found below error logged for rstudio server.

```
 rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2019-08-28 04:50:07 CDT; 11s ago
  Process: 31611 ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -TERM rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31609 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31610 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
           └─20647 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling r...rt.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for rstudio-server....ice
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
Aug 28 04:50:07 nds-vm1.novalocal systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, i have restarted my VM where i am running r-studio server. It seems to have resolved my issue.